# Tensorflow: predict grow factor in a time series forecast

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I am developing an application to predict future hourly online orders on my e-commerce website (time-series problem) using Canned Estimator `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor`

```
    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        hidden_units=hidden_units, 
        model_dir=model_dir, 
        optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01,
                                                l1_regularization_strength=0.001))
```

The features I am using are pretty much based on the date and time. For example, the `csv` file from my training data looks like this

```
year,month,day,weekday,isweekend,hr,weeknum,yearday,orders
2018,7,16,2,0,0,29,197,193
2018,7,16,2,0,1,29,197,131
2018,7,16,2,0,2,29,197,77
2018,7,16,2,0,3,29,197,59
.....
```

where orders column is the target for the model.

The model I got so far is working decently but when I run predictions for a high demand day like Black Friday, it is under-predicting. For example, in the graph below we can see that predictions for Black Friday this year 2018 (dashed line) are not as high as we intuitively expect, even though it predicts the shape nicely.

[image]

With that all being said, I would appreciate any recommendation to add to my model so it can also predict correctly the grow factor and not only the trend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a time series problem, so you're better off using `tf.contrib.timeseries.ARRegressor` (neural network built specifically for time series) or `tf.contrib.timeseries.StructuralEnsembleRegressor` (time series state space model - which ) than a generic neural network.

Both models take an exogenous_feature_columns argument, you could populate that with 0 for normal days and 1 for event days like Black Friday. That would fix your under-predicting problem since otherwise the model would treat those spikes as outliers (you could do this even with a generic neural network - it's just easier to code with the time series specific functions).

On a more general note, I would recommend other tools besides tensorflow for time series forecasting, such as Facebook Prophet or Statsmodels package.

I would go further and recommend that you don't use Python at all, and instead look at using some of the forecasting packages available in R.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Actually, I am very intrigued with your last sentence. I can feel some tension against Python (just an opinion), I would like to hear more about why you don't recommend to use Python at all, if possible.

Comment: @zeellos "I can feel some tension against Python" --- as far as programming languages go, I actually prefer Python to R. It's just that the number of tools available for times series analysis in R are much more mature and extensive than those available in Python.

Comment: @zeellos- I'm using R for all my timeseries modelling, and have been suggested to look into RNN via Keras/Tensorflow by some peers. I was wondering what has your experience using Python for Keras/TF been like vs. Prophet? I've found no comparisons between the two online, and am looking for more information on how the two compare.